# unable to draw a forest below another forest

Tags: texstudio, forest

```
  \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
                    \begin{forest}
                        for tree={draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, rounded corners},
                        forked edges,
                        [\textbf{TextBlob(``who hath relieved you?")}
                        [sentiment("who") [ p~:~0 ]]
                        [sentiment("hath") [p~:~0 ]]
                        [sentiment("relieved") [p~:~0 ]]
                        [sentiment("you") [p~:~0 ]]]
                    \end{forest}
                        \begin{forest}
                        for tree={draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, rounded corners},
                        forked edges,
                        [\textbf{TextBlob(``who hath relieved you?")}
                        [sentiment("who") [ p~:~0 ]]
                        [sentiment("hath") [p~:~0 ]]
                        [sentiment("relieved") [p~:~0 ]]
                        [sentiment("you") [p~:~0 ]]]
                    \end{forest}
                    
                        
            }
```

when i am trying to execute it prints side by side and not one below another in beamer class[image]

Comment: Simple linebreaks in the source are interpreted as a single space for the output. Try a double linebreak (an empty line between the trees), or a \\ (double backslash) after the `\end{forest}` of the first tree.

Comment: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{frame}. when I am trying to add \\. It's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You not provide some important information:

- which document class you use?
- is this two column document?
- why you need to scale your trees? Don't do this, rather redesign your trees (using smaller font size, smaller distance between nodes). In the case, that you persist to use `\resizebox`, than you should use it separately for each of tree (and between them insert empty text line).

So please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` whic reproduce your problem. Assuming, that you use standard `article` document class, a MWE, which solve your problem cab ve:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{forest}
for tree={draw, 
    minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,
    rounded corners,
    font=\small,
forked edge,        % for forked edge
    s sep = 1mm,    % sibling distance
    l sep = 8mm,    % level distance
 fork sep = 4mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
        }
 [\textbf{TextBlob(``who hath relieved you?")}
    [sentiment("who") [ p~:~0 ]]
    [sentiment("hath") [p~:~0 ]]
    [sentiment("relieved") [p~:~0 ]]
    [sentiment("you") [p~:~0 ]]
]
    \end{forest}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={draw,
    minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,
    rounded corners,
    font=\small,
forked edge,        % for forked edge
    s sep = 1mm,    % sibling distance
    l sep = 8mm,    % level distance
 fork sep = 4mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
        }
 [\textbf{TextBlob(``who hath relieved you?")}
    [sentiment("who") [ p~:~0 ]]
    [sentiment("hath") [p~:~0 ]]
    [sentiment("relieved") [p~:~0 ]]
    [sentiment("you") [p~:~0 ]]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show text area borders)

Comment: The top image is indented a bit, the bottom one right at the edge. I'm not sure if that's what the OP wanted. In my opinion, uniform indentation would make more sense.

Comment: @Nico, you are right. Now both are centered. As I see, the main concern of OP is to have threes above each other. Horisontal position is than simple to adjust.